# Automate Microsoft Teams Tab App in AzurePipelines

Tags: powershell, automation, azure-pipelines, microsoft-teams

We are trying to automate a Teams Tab App in our Azure Pipeline, but we are wondering if this even possible. We have already created the zip file for the app which can be uploaded via App Studio and it works. But we don't want the customers to do that via App Studio, instead, we want to automate this process on their pipeline. For that we created the following powershell:

```
# Generate zip file for deployment
$compress = @{
    Path = "color.png", "outline.png", "manifest.json"
    CompressionLevel = "Fastest"
    DestinationPath = "app.zip"
}

Compress-Archive @compress -Update
```

Then we check if `MicrosoftTeams` module is installed, otherwise we install it:

```
# Checks whether MicrosoftTeams module is available
if (Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name "MicrosoftTeams") {
    Write-Verbose "MicrosoftTeams module already installed."
} 
else {
    Write-Verbose "Installing module MicrosoftTeams - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/teams/?view=teams-ps."
    Install-Module MicrosoftTeams
}

Write-Verbose "Importing module MicrosoftTeams."
Import-Module MicrosoftTeams
```

And we connect with Microsoft Teams so we can install the app later:

```
Write-Verbose "Connecting to Microsoft Teams"
$user = "<<the account id>>"
Connect-MicrosoftTeams -AccountId $user
```

The problem here is that I'm always getting the prompt for device authentication:
[image]

Of course this would never work in a pipeline. How can I make this work? Can I use Token to connect with Teams?

Answer (score 5):

You can publish an app using Teams App Submission API to enable it across organization level. Please refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/submit-approve-custom-apps) for more details.

Comment: @DAG Please let us know if your issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

There is an ability to install an app for a user using the Microsoft Graph, which might be a better approach. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/userteamwork-post-installedapps?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http . You can also see the option to list apps, which might be useful to check IDs etc.: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/userteamwork-list-installedapps?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Comment: For a user is not the solution, we need to do this at organizational scope level